# Is there a way to trigger a script from a pop-up menu when the use selects "other…"?

Tags: triggers, filemaker, popupmenu

I am using Filemaker 18 pro advanced on a Mac running Catalina. I have a table with a field "attributes", and a pop-up menu for this field showing all the attributes already assigned to any of the records in this table. This pop-up also allows the user to enter a new attribute. So the user can either select a previously entered attribute or to add a new attribute by selecting "other…" (or is it "other..."). If the user selects "other…", I would like to be able to trigger a script that replaces the usual result of selecting "other…". Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "*replaces the usual result of selecting "other…"*"? The usual result is a window that opens to get user's input. I don't think you can replace that.

Comment: Thanks, yes, you understood my question. I understand that you don't think it possible.

Comment: It's not possible the way you're trying it. It might be possible through other means. But I am still not sure what exactly is your purpose here. What would your script do that's different from the built-in action?

Comment: Hi Michael. What I wanted to replace the standard action of clicking on  "other…" was to bring up a custom (card) layout that would take the user's name and associate it with the added text as well as allowing the user to make a comment about her addition. You may also have read my comment to nsmadira in which I agree that all this is possible using a drop-down list. My only complaint with that is an aesthetic one: I prefer the look of the popup menu.

Comment: If you want to use a pop-up menu, then your best option, IMHO, is to have an `Other…` button next to the field. Otherwise you would have to include a dummy `" Other…"` value in one or all of your records, and have your script triggered by selection of this value. Quite a lot of work for such minor detail.

Answer (score 1):

You could set your popup menu to draw from a field PopUpMenu in a single-record table such as ValueLists (ValueLists::PopUpMenu). Then you could create a custom UI to modify your value list. The caveat is that the "Other..." option you described would bypass your custom Value List Management UI so you'd have to prohibit modification of the value list in the pop-up menu definition.

Additionally, you would need to add a button near the field to access the Value List Management UI. To avoid adding a button, you could convert your pop-up menu to a drop-down list, which allow manual entries, and add an onObjectSave script trigger which would call a script that checks ValueLists::PopUpMenu for the entered value. If the entered value is not found, you can spawn the Value List Management UI to add it to your value list in a completely customizable way, which sounds like your initial intent.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the drop-down list seems to be more flexible than the pop-up menu, and that is what I am now using. (I had hoped to use the pop-up menu because is it, to my thinking, the slightly more aesthetic choice.)